# Power BI Report Builder: How do I have a row header for each parent group

Tags: powerbi, dax, reportbuilder3.0

I am building a report that looks like this: [Power BI Report Builder Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdjwT.png)

As this currently stands, when you go to the preview only the parent group and the aggregation for the parent group displays. However, clicking a plus arrow next to the parent group expands to show the child details group. The child details group are the specific cases that make up the summary of the parent group. The parent group is sorted in alphabetical order and when you expand the first parent group to reveal the child details group, you are shown the header row underlined in red (starting with "Location" in the provided image). However, when you expand the parent groups that follow, that header row does not show. Only the details with no header show.

For the header row visibility (starting with "Location") I am using the following expression: =IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) = 1, False, True).

Can I modify this expression or do something else to show the header above the details for each parent row group?

Thanks!

Provided that formula and expected the header to show up for each component of the row group. Not just the first one.